# #define SOMETHING of type int16_t

Tags: c, macros

How does one define different types of ints?

I have the following

```
struct movCommand
{
    uint8_t type;
    uint8_t order;
    int16_t height;
    uint16_t distance;
    int16_t yaw;
};
```

and need to define these according to the types they are.

What is the correct syntax for `#define` when selecting the type for the define?

EDIT :

It looks like my question has been misunderstood.

I want to do this `#define LANDING_COMMAND "2"`
But I want to set the type of the landing command because it needs to be int16_t

Comment: If you want it to be an `int16_t` you shouldn't be using `"2"`. That's a `char *`.

Comment: You could do `#define LANDING_COMMAND ((int16_t)2)`, but understand that (1) this doesn't define a variable but a preprocessor macro, and (2) you can assign 2 to a `unit16_t` variable anyway, even though 2 has type `int` it will convert implicitly. Conversely an `int16_t` will convert to `int` (or some other type at least as large) in any arithmetic expression. So there's rarely much to be gained by giving it `int16_t` type.

Comment: @Steve: So any int16_t or e.g. uint8_t will be converted to int implicitly?

Comment: both of those have implicit conversions to int, yes.

Answer (score 4):

You do not use `#define` for this. You `#include <stdint.h>`

Comment: More generally, you shouldn't be `#define mytype int`, you should be using `typedef`.

Comment: Yes, but you should never `typedef` names that are defined in the standard unless you can ensure that the standard headers which define them will never be included.

Comment: Of course. That's why I said "More generally." The OP seems pretty confused about `typedef`s overall.

Comment: I edited my question. It was misleading. I dont want to define what exists. I want to set the type of value that is defined to a specific tag

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using the `#define` directive, I'd use a `typedef`, which is how the standard-library would define them inside of `<stdint.h>` (at least on a C99-compatible platform).  If you look in that header, you'll see how they're defined specifically on their platform.  Typical `typedefs` will be:

```
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
typedef signed char int8_t;
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
typedef signed short int16_t;
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
typedef int int32_t;
//... etc., etc.
```

There's a lot more `typedef`'s defined inside the header file, including 64-bit types, etc.

Comment: `int8_t` is almost surely `signed char`, not simply `char`, which might change signedness depending on various things, even compiler options that can be set by the user.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with C99, you can use the `typedef`s from `<stdint.h>` or `<inttypes.h>` (and `<inttypes.h>` might be available even if `<stdint.h>` is not - in non-C99 compilers).

If they are available (they usually are), all the types you show will be provided by those headers.

In general, a `typedef` is preferable to a `#define`.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to your new question, the `#define` is replaced literally with the text you provide. So

```
#define LANDING_COMMAND "2";
```

Will replace all uses of `LANDING_COMMAND` with `"2";` in the program text. This is probably *not* what you want.

First, preprocessing directives are *not* part of the C language, they're part of the preprocessor. Since they're not part of C, they're not statements, so they don't end with `;`. If you leave that in, it will likely cause problems if you intend to do things like `func(LANDING_COMMAND);`.

Second, `"2"` is of type `char *`, which is not convertible to `int16_t` with any safety. You need to use a literal `2` for the numeric value.

Lastly, to make it type `int16_t`, you'll need to provide either a cast (`((int16_t)2)`) <strike>or use the macro `INT16_C(2)` which expands to a literal with the appropriate suffix to make it of size (and type) `int16_t`. I recommend the latter, but the former should work</strike>. The macro `INT16_C(2)` could be used, but it expands to a literal (with the appropriate suffix) of type `int_least16_t`, which is close but no cigar. `stdint.h` only provides macros to make integer constant literals of the `[u]int_leastN_t` types and the `[u]intmax_t` types, not more generally for the `[u]intN_t` or `[u]int_fastN_t` types. Why they don't is beyond me.

Comment: so something like this #define MOVING_COMMAND INT16_C(2)

Comment: @Helium3 - I looked it up and was wrong, and have revised my answer. Unfortunately `INT16_C(2)` provides a constant of type `int_least16_t`. The `stdint.h` header provides no equivalent macro for `int16_t` or other types. I'm not sure what the reason for this omission is.

Comment: Ok Thanks. so no macros for that then :)

Comment: But will this work when casting ((uint8_t)MANUAL);  MANUAL being a macro to a normal int?

Comment: `int_leastNN_t` **is the same** as `intNN_t` provided the latter exists. Therefore the macros also yield values of the right type for `intNN_t`; defining them in terms of `int_leastNN_t` just ensures that they can do something useful even if `intNN_t` does not exist.

Comment: If preprocessing directives aren't part of the C language, what are they doing specified in "International Standard ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 Programming Languages -- C"? More precisely, in Chapter 6 "Language"?

Comment: @Steve - You know what I mean. They're not part of the C syntax, as the OP's original `#define` seemed to suggest (since it ended with a semicolon).

Answer (score 0):

include stdint.h gives you 8, 16, 32, and 64 signed and unsigned.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you describe.  Other answers have indicated workarounds.  As for your specific question, from the [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew2hz0yd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> Expressions must have integral type
>   and can include only integer
>   constants, character constants, and
>   the defined operator.
>
> The expression cannot use sizeof or a
>   type-cast operator.

Answer (score 0):

`#define` doesn't have a type. It's exactly the same as find/replace in your editor. 
You can do

```
#define LANDING_COMMAND 2
...
my_movCommand.yaw = LANDING_COMMAND;
```

The compiler will do the right type conversions for you, but if you insist on a type `int16_t` then

```
#define LANDING_COMMAND ((int16_t)2)
```

Comment: `#define` doesn't have a type, but the _constant_ has a type. In this case, `LANDING_COMMAND` is of type `int` when it is expanded.

Comment: I don't see the need to add explicit types here, but I added a define with typing.

Comment: OP asked for an explicit type, so we provide. Where is `static_cast` in the C language?

Comment: It should. I still don't get why you want the type in there.